# User: [someLogin] has an unresolved reference to Login [someLogin]

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm getting this issue while trying to update the database using EF CF Migrations. 
I'm using VS2013 Ultimate Preview and SQL Server 2012, and I create the DbContext .cs-file and add a connection string to Web.config.
So when I'm trying to update database from PackageManager Console, it goes

```
An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.
```

The connection string is

```
<add name="SomeDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=someDB.mssql.somedomain.com;Initial Catalog=someDB;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=someLogin;Password=somePassword;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=someDB.mssql.somedomain.com"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and I'm quite sure it's correct, because I could access the database manually using Data Connections in Server Explorer and pulled the connection string from there and checked it with the one recommended by hosting, and it fits.

Double-clicking the error (SQL71501) suggests me to change this SQL query:

```
CREATE USER [someLogin] FOR LOGIN [someLogin]
```

I am not using Database Projects, where this issue could be found a lot.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to create brand-new database via EF CodeFirst mechanisms? I mean try changing the database name and creating the new one from scratch. If everything is ok then the problem probably in your update scripts. Have you got any custom update scripts or you use the EF-generated ones?

Comment: You know, all is magically working now. I just added another migration and updated with -verbose flag to see the query. 

I use the Migrations command as Update-Database with previously added simple initial migration to create a couple of tables.

I'm not sure that any custom scripts will make any difference, because first migrations are pretty easy. It's probably server stuff.